# What is the problem with the following code using constructors for sorting strings?

Tags: c++, string, class, sorting, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
class sorting
{
private:
    char str[10];
public:
    sorting() {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
            cin>>str[i];
        }
    }
    void sort() {
        int i,j;
        char temp;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
             for(j=i+1;j<10;j++) {
                 if(strcmp(str[j],str[j+1])>0) {
                     strcpy(temp,str[j]);
                     strcpy(str[j],str[j+1]);
                     strcpy(str[j+1],temp);
                 }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
            cout<<str[i];
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    sorting s1;
    cout<<s1.sort();
    return 0;
}
```

This is a code I have written to sort strings using constructors. It gives me error in the if condition of the code where I have used strcmp. Please review this for I could not get the desired output and it gives me errors.

Comment: You seem to be sorting characters, not strings. You shouldn't do these kinds on operations in a constructor. And note the existence of [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Comment: I have seen strcpy while sorting strings. I have used it here for swapping@rafix07

Comment: `str[j]` accesses a single `char,` while `strcmp()` wants `const char*`.  Same for `temp` and `stdcpy()`. VTC as typo.

Comment: `for(j=i+1;j<10;j++)` and `strcpy(str[j+1],temp);` does not match `char str[10];`.

Comment: There is no use of constructor in what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem 1

Like someone already pointed out, you cant use `strcopy` on chars. If you want to create a string array i would suggest using either `char**` or `std::string*`.

## Problem 2

In your nested loop you will get an `index out of bounds` error, due to the fact that once `i` reaches a value of `8`, `j` will be `9`, which means that when you try to access `str[j+1]` which evaluates to `str[10]`, you will get said error.

Comment: `std::array` and `std::vector` should be prefered over c-style arrays. `std::vector<std::string>` should be the first suggestion.